# How do I get a count on the affected rows from an operation on a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data set, loaded into a Pandas DataFrame

| BARCODE | ALTERNATE_BARCODE |
| --- | --- |
|  | 123 |
| 456 | 789 |

Imagine I have the following Pandas python Statement:

```
users.loc[users["BARCODE"] == "", "BARCODE"] = users["ALTERNATE_BARCODE"]
```

Is there any way - without rewriting this terse statement too much - that would allow me to access the number of rows in the DataFrame that got affected?

**Edit**: I am mainly on the lookout for the existence of a library or something build into Pandas that has knowledge of the last operation and could provide me with some metadata about it. Deltas is a good workaround, but not what I am after, since it would clutter the code.

Comment: `users["BARCODE"].eq("").sum()`? (you obviously need to run it before replacing the values)

Comment: `I am mainly on the lookout for the existence of a library or something build into Pandas that has knowledge of the last operation and could provide me with some metadata about it` - no, it not exist.

Comment: How can one lift the Similar question ban of the one? The related question has very little to do with what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to replacing the values, get the length output of the .loc command.

```
len(users.loc[users["BARCODE"] == "", "BARCODE"].index)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am on the lookout for more of  something that could provide me with metadata about the operation.

Comment: @Fontanka16
The best solution would be to use a [walrus](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to assign a part of a .loc surrounded by brackets to a variable, use assignment operation outside of brackets and then access the length using .shape function on a variable. So something like `(affected := users.loc[users["BARCODE"] == "", "BARCODE"]) = users["ALTERNATE_BARCODE"]` and `affected.shape[0]`